# Spark Error: Total size of serialized results of 268 tasks (1442.5 MB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (1024.0 MB)

Tags: apache-spark

I am running a Spark job and here I am getting following error. I have tried a lot to optimize

Now the code is throwing outofmemory error. I have increased the partitions. I am trying to run Spark program in eclipse, the two tables contains 4 millions records each. I am trying to join and export into a single JSON file. When I am running the program then after 20 minutes I am getting OutOfMemory error.

```scala
      val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SQLtoJSON").setMaster("local[*]")
      .set("spark.executor.memory", "7g")
      .set("spark.driver.memory", "8g")
      .set("spark.executor.cores", "4")
  //  .set("spark.driver.cores", "4")
      .set("spark.testing.memory", "2147480000")
        .set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "2000")
```

Error:

```scala
18/08/13 12:07:07 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 94 (show at SparkApplication.scala:132) failed in 54.206 s due to Job aborted due to stage failure: Total size of serialized results of 268 tasks (1442.5 MB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (1024.0 MB)
18/08/13 12:07:07 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 12 failed: show at SparkApplication.scala:132, took 754.916325 s
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Total size of serialized results of 268 tasks (1442.5 MB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (1024.0 MB)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1517)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1505)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
```

Comment: Are you trying to collect the data somewhere

Comment: Not collect exactly. Joining one table with another and the size is increasing itself

Comment: Any solution? I have set the spark.driver.maxresultsize to 3GB

Comment: It’s failing as its exceeding the result size of driver. If you want unlimited mark it 0. Unless you will get the result to driver our code should not fail. Paste your complete code for further analysis

Comment: Please check my code, I have updated the question.

Comment: It must be failing in coalsce(1) as it get all the data from the partitions into one and write. Try to give 0 to the max result setting

Comment: How to give 0 to the max result setting? I didnt get you

Comment: spark.driver.maxresultsize=  “0g” prior to that cache the dataframe and see how much memory it’s taking in serialised format

Comment: You are saying that I have to check that how much memory it is taking by setting 0GB right? After that I will set that size in maxResultSize, am I right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177924/discussion-between-bhaskar-das-and-chandan).

Comment: Please check my updated comments

Comment: How much memory it consumed

Comment: Please check the chat box

Comment: Input size is 54 GB